# Android SQlite database, what is in a TEXT value if I create an entry but specify no string for it?

Tags: android, sqlite

In Android, which I think uses SQlite3
If you create a table with two TEXT values

Then you go to make an entry in that table but specify no value for the second TEXT field, what will happen?

I'm new to SQL, just started MySQL and this SQlite.

Comment: do you mean an empty string?

Comment: null, or you get constrain exception if you created the table by forcing the fields to be not null.

Comment: Why didn't you just try it?

Answer (score 1):

the default value probably would be null

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).